# Why do rows in my list box have different different heights on different machines?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am setting up a database and I have set up some VBA code to resize a list box within a report based on the number of records in the list box so that the list box will always be just the right size when printing. The problem I am having is that the resizing works perfectly on my machine, however when I ran the code on another machine the last record was cut off by the list box.

In an attempt to see if either machine was behaving oddly I ran the code on a 3rd machine to see what would happen and the last record was not cut off but was in a slightly different position to on the original machine, so I had 3 different heights for the list box required. I checked the values of the variables in the VBA code on both of the first 2 machines and the calculations are identical. I have checked that the font is the same and the font size is the same and the padding is the same.

```
Dim RecordCount as Integer
Dim FontSize as Integer
Dim Padding as Integer
Dim RowHeight as Integer

Dim lstIssues as Listbox
Dim Issues as Report
Set Issues = [Reports]![Issues]
Set lstIssues = Issues.lstIssues

RecordCount = lstIssues.ListCount
FontSize = lstIssues.FontSize
Padding = lstIssues.TopPadding + lstIssues.BottomPadding

RowHeight = 20 * FontSize + Padding

lstIssues.Height = RowHeight * RecordCount

On Error Resume Next

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPrint

On Error GoTo 0
```

Font size in my database is 11 and top and bottom padding are both 0.053cm or 30 twips each. RowHeight should thus be 280. Record count in my table is 24 so total listbox height should be 6720.

Comment: Could be to do with screen resolution and/or scaling?

Comment: I've now since tested both of these and both screen resolution and scaling are the same on each pc.

Comment: Physically measure the font heights on the three machines. Measure the list box row heights as well. This will help narrow in on what the problem may be.

Comment: One code note: you should put a limit on how high `lstIssues` can get.

Comment: This is the kind of comment I don't like to read, but: making this work exactly the same everywhere may be out of your control. Why not make it work for most people, and move on to other problems?

Comment: Check out this MS Article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/automatic-scaling-in-windows-forms